# Submit topology to storm cluster failed due to org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: tcp, connection, apache-storm

when I submit my topo to nimbus cluster in storm, it failed due to :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.storm.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.retryNext(TBackoffConnect.java:64)
at org.apache.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:56)
at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:99)
at org.apache.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.<init>(ThriftClient.java:69)
at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:106)
at org.apache.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClientAs(NimbusClient.java:78)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyAs(StormSubmitter.java:228)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopology(StormSubmitter.java:288)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(StormSubmitter.java:324)
at org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter.submitTopologyWithProgressBar(StormSubmitter.java:305)
```

I have searched a lot in google, I met all conditions to submit the topo.But it still failed. And I have used 'tcpdump' tool that catched the packages between nimbus server and client in 6627 port. And it's confused to me is that in my access-nimbus.log, it has record it is received the request from the client:

```
2016-08-10 12:56:17.437 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 4 access from:  principal:  operation: getClusterInfo
```

I know if it submits topo successfully, the access-nimbus.log will records as following:

> 2016-07-19 10:10:35.883 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 19 access from:  principal:  operation: getClusterInfo
>   2016-07-19 10:10:35.883 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 20 access from:  principal:  operation: getClusterInfo
>   2016-07-19 10:10:35.887 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 21 access from:  principal:  operation: getClusterInfo
>   2016-07-19 10:10:35.887 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 22 access from:  principal:  operation: getClusterInfo
>   2016-07-19 10:10:35.890 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 23 access from:  principal:  operation: getNimbusConf
>   2016-07-19 10:12:24.989 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 24 access from:  principal:  operation: getClusterInfo
>   2016-07-19 10:12:25.005 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 25 access from:  principal:  operation: getClusterInfo
>   2016-07-19 10:12:25.011 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 26 access from:  principal:  operation: getClusterInfo
>   2016-07-19 10:12:25.020 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 27 access from:  principal:  operation: getClusterInfo
>   2016-07-19 10:12:25.077 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 28 access from:  principal:  operation: fileUpload
>   ...
>   2016-07-19 10:12:25.405 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 31 access from:  principal:  operation: fileUpload
>   2016-07-19 10:12:25.426 o.a.s.l.ThriftAccessLogger [INFO] Request ID: 32 access from:  principal:  operation: submitTopology

So what can I do ?

P.S.
1) I have closed the server's firewall

2) the nimbus's port (6627) is listened also

3) the zookeeper is run normal

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too today!
I Just restarted storm cluster!
it's resolved！
I don't know  whether you resolved this error yet！
but you can try to restart!

Comment: Restarting the cluster would likely work around the problem but that doesn't explain why it happened in the first place or how to avoid it.

Comment: Yes ！You are right ！I just resolved.actually i really don't know how to work